# CSS animation not working for a-tag

Tags: css, animation

In the [following demonstration](http://codepen.io/SauravTom/pen/Jougx), I am trying to apply bouncing animation to three elements, a div, p-tag and a-tag , its not working for the a-tag.

Any clues what might be wrong ?

link:

http://codepen.io/SauravTom/pen/Jougx

Comment: You could put a <p class="bounce"></p> around it

Comment: Ya, but .. it should be working without it as well, shouldn't it ?

Comment: `<a>` are inline elements so they won't obey any height or width set in CSS unless you change the display property to `block` or `inline-block`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `display:block` or `display:inline-block`on the `a` tag.

You can't use margins or scaling on inline elements.

Here's an updated example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/odiuz